# aura:if displays false condition by default

Tags: aura, aura-if

I have a combobox where user selects LWC or Aura as component type and a boolean variable islwc which I am setting when user clicks submit button

```
In cmp,
   <aura:attribute name="islwc" type="Boolean"/>
   <lightning:combobox name="componentnames" label="Components" placeholder="Select component type 
   to view.." options="{!v.components}" onchange="{!c.handleComponentChange}" />
   <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" title="Submit" onclick="{!c.handleSubmit}" />
```

```
In JScontroller, 
           handleSubmit : function (component, event, helper) {

                var comp= component.get("v.selectedComponent");
                if(comp=='Lwc'){
                    component.set("v.islwc", true);
    
                }
                else if (comp=='Aura'){
                    component.set("v.islwc", false);
                }

            }
```

If it is LWC i want to call LWC child component else Aura child component for which I am using aura:if

```
    <aura:if isTrue="{! or (v.islwc)}">

        <c:displayRecordDetailsLWC recordIdDetail="{!v.recordidinput}" objectName="{!v.objectname}">
        </c:displayRecordDetailsLWC>

        <aura:set attribute="else">

        <c:displayRecordDetailsChild recordIdDetail="{!v.recordidinput}" objectName="   {!v.objectname}">
            </c:displayRecordDetailsChild>

        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
```

Everytime the page is opened, by default the Aura component(False condition) is loaded.
[image]

I want to totally hide all child components and display them only when the data is submitted.

EDIT: On trying Caspar's code by adding a boolean attribute and setting an or condition, I still get the above Aura component. And when I set the component to LWC, both are displayed like below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can set defaults to your attributes.

```
<aura:attribute name="islwc" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
```

If you want to hide BOTH components, you'll need another attribute - `loaded` for example.

```
<aura:attribute name="isloaded" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
```

Then use that in your condition:

```
    <aura:if isTrue="{! or(v.islwc,v.isloaded)}">
        <c:displayRecordDetailsLWC recordIdDetail="{!v.recordidinput}" objectName="{!v.objectname}">
        </c:displayRecordDetailsLWC>
    </aura:if>
    
    <aura:if isTrue="{! or(not(v.islwc),v.isloaded)}">
       <c:displayRecordDetailsChild recordIdDetail="{!v.recordidinput}" objectName="   {!v.objectname}">
        </c:displayRecordDetailsChild>
    </aura:if>
```

I skipped the `else` condition, because I think it messes up the markup too much btw - and 2 `if` conditions work fine.

In your `handleSubmit` condition, set `isloaded` to true.

```
handleSubmit : function (component, event, helper) {
  component.set("v.isloaded", true);
  ...etc
```

Comment: I added this and by changing the isfTrue to <aura:if isTrue="{v.islwc,v.isloaded}"> & <aura:if isTrue="{not(v.islwc),v.isloaded}"> the components do not show. However, they don't show on clicking the submit button (even though I added a console.log statement and both the attributes return correct values)

Comment: What about the `or()` statement that I have in my example?

Comment: On including or it was showing again for the false condition. I think ! stands for default or something. Not sure

Comment: The `!` tells the parser that there is an expression to evaluate. You need it. Put this exact code in the `isTrue` expression: `{! or(v.islwc,v.isloaded)}`. Then make sure that your capitalization is correct and that both attributes exist, are of type `Boolean` and have defaults set correctly.

Comment: Edited the question with a picture, the expression still shows default Aura and on choosing lwc it shows both the components somehow.

Comment: actually, try `and` ie `{! and(v.islwc,v.isloaded)}`

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you